# What is the facebook Oauth grant type redirect url for react native app

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I am using this https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth.

```
try {
        const result = await authorize({
            serviceConfiguration: {
                authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth',
                tokenEndpoint: `fb131XXXXXXX034://token-url`,
                },
            clientId: '131XXXXXXX034',
            redirectUrl: 'fb131XXXXXXX034://authorize',
            scopes: ['email'],
        });
            console.log('Done');
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        }
```

The above code is opening a facebook signin form and if logged in "continue" option but it is not redirecting back to my react native app in **Android** (didnt work on IOS yet) after login or clicking continue button. What should I give to redirect back to app?

Tried:
in app/ build.gradle

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
             appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.<app-name>.app'
        ]
```

`redirectUrl: 'com.<app-name>.app:/oauth2redirect/facebook-provider'`, it is giving me error URL not supported.

Tried:
in app/build.gradle

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
           appAuthRedirectScheme: 'https://app.<app-name>.com/oauth2redirect'
        ]
```

`redirectUrl: 'https://app.<app-name>.com/oauth2redirect'` it is trying to open https://app.app-name.com and because there is no website with that domain it is giving site not reached error

Comment: The documentation of the module explains how to do it by adding some info to your AndroidManifest.xml file and using it with the `redirectUrl` value (the value you use in the `android:scheme` is the `redirectUrl`) - https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-android#capturing-the-authorization-redirect

Comment: Hi, I tried custom scheme URI , redirectUrl: 'com.<app-name>.app:/oauth2redirect/facebook-provider', it is giving me error URL not supported. I also tried redirectUrl: 'https://app.<app-name>.com/oauth2redirect' it is trying to open https://app.<app-name>.com and because there is no website with that domain it is giving site not reached error

Comment: If in your build.gradle file you have `com.labl.app` then you use the exact same thing as your `redirectUrl` (no `https://`). Check the example project in the repository here (same domain as in build.gradle) - https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/master/Example/AndroidExample/App.js#L19

Comment: I tried that way too. It is giving REdirect URL not supported error when using custom Scheme